# Can the methods of FunSearch that have been applied to the cap set problem be also applied to the enumeration of maximal antichains of sets?

Tags: large-language-models, deepmind, combinatorics

Today on a seminar we discussed with colleagues recent impressive [breakthrough](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06924-6) in the [cap set problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cap_set) using Google DeepMind's [FunSearch](https://github.com/google-deepmind/funsearch?tab=readme-ov-file). The following specific question has been raised. Among several very similar problems in extremal combinatorics, let us consider the one of enumerating maximal antichains in the powersets of finite sets (including finding good upper or lower bounds for their number).

The question: is it feasible to readily apply the methods of FunSearch to this problem?

About the problem in some more detail. The sequence $a(n)$ in question is [A326358](https://oeis.org/A326358), it starts with

1, 2, 3, 7, 29, 376, 31746, 123805914

One possible definition is this: for each $n=0,1,2,3,...$ consider the following graph $G_n$. It has $2^n$ vertices, identified with all possible subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$. Two such subsets $S$ and $T$ are joined with an edge if neither $S\subseteq T$ nor $T\subseteq S$ holds. Then $a(n)$ is the number of maximal cliques (complete subgraphs) in the graph $G_n$.

For example (see the above link [A326358](https://oeis.org/A326358)), $a(3)=7$ since there are exactly $7$ maximal cliques in $G_3$. Namely, these maximal cliques are:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\{\varnothing\}\\
&\{\{1,2,3\}\}\\
&\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\}\\
&\{\{2\},\{1,3\}\}\\
&\{\{3\},\{1,2\}\}\\
&\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\}\\
&\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}
\end{aligned}  
$$

The above OEIS page contains $a(n)$ for $n<8$. I don't know whether anybody has computed $a(8)$. I have supplied $a(6)$ and $a(7)$ using the [GAP](https://www.gap-system.org/) package [GRAPE](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/grape.html) which works by taking into account any symmetries present in the graph. Note that the graphs $G_n$ are indeed highly symmetric.

So, can the LLM methods of FunSearch give some further progress here?